# Tab indicator and its text got shrinked after the addition of several tabs

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How do I fix this. When I added 10 tabs ..the tab indicator and its text got shrinked . I'm using the tabLayout from latest support library. ﻿

Please let me know if you need any further info.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I'm really sorry. app:tabMode was set to fixed.

should be

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```